# Optimizely CMS 12- How to customize admin pages?

Tags: c#, .net, content-management-system, episerver, optimizely

I'm using optimizely CMS 12 and I need to add a new menu item as a new tab after "Display Option" for My Settings Page

I need to add a new tab after Display Option

[image]

Went through [this](https://docs.developers.optimizely.com/content-cloud/v12.0.0-content-cloud/docs/adding-and-configuring-menu-items) link and I tried several ways but those did not work. can anyone suggest me way of implementing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked this with Optimizely, they mentioned that this is not possible to do in CMS 12.